# Unmarshal a nested json without a key

Tags: json, go, struct, unmarshalling, kraken.com

I am not unable to cast the following `json` in a struct in Golang, received from `Kraken` API:

```
{
    "error": [],
    "result": {
        "LINKUSD": {
            "asks": [
                ["2.049720", "183.556", 1576323009],
                ["2.049750", "555.125", 1576323009],
                ["2.049760", "393.580", 1576323008],
                ["2.049980", "206.514", 1576322995]
            ],
            "bids": [
                ["2.043800", "20.691", 1576322350],
                ["2.039080", "755.396", 1576323007],
                ["2.036960", "214.621", 1576323006],
                ["2.036930", "700.792", 1576322987]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Using `json-to-go`, he gives me the following struct:

```golang
type AutoGenerated struct {
    Error  []interface{} `json:"error"`
    Result struct {
        LINKUSD struct {
            Asks [][]interface{} `json:"asks"`
            Bids [][]interface{} `json:"bids"`
        } `json:"LINKUSD"`
    } `json:"result"`
}
```

Obviously, i can't hardocode the `LINKUSD` cause it will change for every currency pairs.

I've created two structure for accomplish the task, but i'm not able to cast the result in the struct.

```golang
type BitfinexOrderBook struct {
    Pair string          `json:"pair"`
    Asks []BitfinexOrder `json:"asks"`
    Bids []BitfinexOrder `json:"bids"`
}

type BitfinexOrder struct {
    Price     string
    Volume    string
    Timestamp time.Time
}
```

My first attempt was to use reflection. Reading the JSON data posted above, i'm able to retrieve an interface that contains the `asks` and `bids` list.

```golang
// Just used as a divisor
const div string = " ---------------------------------"
func test(data []byte) error {
    var err error

    // Creating the maps for the JSON data
    m := map[string]interface{}{}

    // Parsing/Unmarshalling the json readed from the file
    err = json.Unmarshal(data, &m)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error unmarshalling data: " + err.Error())
        return err
    }

    // Extract the "result" only
    a := reflect.ValueOf(m["result"])

    if a.Kind() == reflect.Map {
        key := a.MapKeys()[0] // Extract the key -> LINKUSD
        log.Println("KEY: ", key, div)
        strct := a.MapIndex(key) // Extract the value -> asks and bids array
        log.Println("MAP: ", strct, div)
        m, _ := strct.Interface().(map[string]interface{})
        log.Println("Asks: ", m["asks"], div) // This will print [[value, value, value] ...] related to asks
        log.Println("Bids: ", m["bids"], div) // This will print [[value, value, value] ...] related to bids

        // Parse the interface into a []byte
        asks_data, err := json.Marshal(m["asks"])
        log.Println("OK: ", err, div)
        log.Println("ASKS: ", string(asks_data), div)
        // Tried without array to (datastructure.BitfinexOrder)
        var asks []datastructure.BitfinexOrder
        err = json.Unmarshal(asks_data, &asks)
        log.Println("ERROR: ", err, div)
        log.Println("UNMARSHAL: ", asks, div)

    }
    return errors.New("UNABLE_PARSE_VALUE")
}
```

The two print below `m, _ := strct.Interface().(map[string]interface{})` will show the following similar data that i'm not able to cast due to the fact that are of `interface` type:

```
[[2.049720 183.556 1.576323009e+09] [2.049750 555.125 1.576323009e+09] [2.049760 393.580 1.576323008e+09] [2.049980 206.514 1.576322995e+09]]
```

But i'm not able to unmarshal the data.

So i've tried with a different function provided by `@chmike`:

```golang
// UnmarshalJSON decode a BifinexOrder.
func UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) (datastructure.BitfinexOrder, error) {
    var packedData []json.Number

    var order datastructure.BitfinexOrder
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &packedData)
    if err != nil {
        return order, err
    }
    order.Price = packedData[0].String()
    order.Volume = packedData[1].String()
    t, err := packedData[2].Int64()
    if err != nil {
        return order, err
    }
    order.Timestamp = time.Unix(t, 0)
    return order, nil
}
```

But i receive the following error:

`json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type json.Number`

Some tips?

***NOTE***: *My previous questions was closed as a duplicate of "Unmarshal 2 different structs in a slice". But, if you read the questions, i'm not dealing with two different structs... I'm dealing with a json that contains a key that i does not know at prior. I'm not able to marshal BitfinexOrder too*

Comment: You need to implement `UnmarshalJSON` on the `*BitfinexOrder` type as a method not a function.

Comment: And, whenever you don't know the keys in the json beforehand use a `map`, there is just no other way apart from parsing the json yourself.

Comment: @mkopriva Really? This is new for me. What change to implement the function as a method instead of implement it as a struct method? I mean: `func (o *BitfinexOrder) UnmarshalJSON` will fix?

Comment: When you implement it as a method it will be called automatically by `json.Unmarshal`, and with the correct part of the json.

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/z6HWleeTvPT is this what you looking for? (I've copied chmike's Unmarshal implementation)

Comment: This is pure magic! Please, write as a response so i can mark you as solver!

Comment: You can delete this question as it is really a duplicate and i've copied the relevant code from chmike's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found from @mkopriva and @chmike:

Thank you guys!

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "encoding/json"
)

var data = []byte(`{
    "error": [],
    "result": {
        "LINKUSD": {
            "asks": [
                ["2.049720", "183.556", 1576323009],
                ["2.049750", "555.125", 1576323009],
                ["2.049760", "393.580", 1576323008],
                ["2.049980", "206.514", 1576322995]
            ],
            "bids": [
                ["2.043800", "20.691", 1576322350],
                ["2.039080", "755.396", 1576323007],
                ["2.036960", "214.621", 1576323006],
                ["2.036930", "700.792", 1576322987]
            ]
        }
    }
}`)

type Response struct {
    Error  []interface{}          `json:"error"`
    Result map[string]Order `json:"result"`
}

type Order struct {
    Asks []BitfinexOrder `json:"asks"`
    Bids []BitfinexOrder `json:"bids"`
}

type BitfinexOrder struct {
    Price     string
    Volume    string
    Timestamp time.Time
}

// UnmarshalJSON decode a BifinexOrder.
func (b *BitfinexOrder) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var packedData []json.Number
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &packedData)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    b.Price = packedData[0].String()
    b.Volume = packedData[1].String()
    t, err := packedData[2].Int64()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    b.Timestamp = time.Unix(t, 0)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    res := &Response{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, res); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for key, value := range res.Result {
        fmt.Println(key)
        for i, ask := range value.Asks {
            fmt.Printf("Asks[%d] = %#v\n", i, ask)
        }
        for i, bid := range value.Bids {
            fmt.Printf("Bids[%d] = %#v\n", i, bid)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be wise to check, in `func (b *BitfinexOrder) UnmarshalJSON`, that `len(packedData) == 3`.

Comment: Thank you for comment! It's a standard API from kraken.com. So, if the "error" is not populated, i can be sure that the data are 3.

Comment: An API may *claim* it always provides three items, and then actually provide 1, or 50. Always validate your input! See https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: order book have every time 3 values: https://www.kraken.com/en-gb/features/api#get-order-book.