# Custom JSON struct Unmarshal

Tags: json, go

I'm using an API that returns the result as the name of the object and I am trying to unmarshal just the fields of the struct. Here is an example of the JSON:

```
{
  "AAPL": {
   "symbol": "AAPL",
    "description": "Apple Inc. - Common Stock",
    "lastPrice": 284.45,
    "openPrice": 284.69,
    "highPrice": 284.89,
    "lowPrice": 282.9197,
  }
}
```

You can see it is using "AAPL" as the name of the struct and I'm not sure how to unmarshal it. I'm looking to unmarshal into this struct:

```
type Quote struct {
    Symbol                    string  `json:"symbol"`
    Description               string  `json:"description"`
    LastPrice                 float64 `json:"lastPrice"`
    OpenPrice                 int     `json:"openPrice"`
    HighPrice                 int     `json:"highPrice"`
    LowPrice                  int     `json:"lowPrice"`
}
```

I assume I need to write a custom unmarshal func

```
func (q *Quote) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
...
}
```

I'm not sure of the contents. Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: If it's always AAPL, use a wrapper struct to hold the quote (https://play.golang.com/p/02F2gYgGuIa). If the object key holding the quote is not always known upfront, use a map (https://play.golang.com/p/2iTXmp82eY-).

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks; the second option helps a bit as the object key is not known and varies by quote (AAPL, AMZN, IBM, etc.) I'll see if I can get this to work in a custom UnmarshalJSON. I'm looking to make a wrapper around the API.

Comment: Use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59338416/cast-json-that-contains-interface-in-properly-struct

Comment: Note that you probably want `float` for the open, high, and low prices as well. Or maybe `string`, or a decimal-based floating point numeric package...

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the suggestions. I had to Alias the quote class in the custom unmarshal func to avoid a loop then use a copier library to copy the struct but used @mkopriva suggestion. Not pretty but it works. I wasn't able to make any of the other suggestions work. Here is how I was able to get it to work: https://play.golang.com/p/zYTTMqjrLmS

Comment: @AndyW. no need for importing the extra package, just use conversion and assignment https://play.golang.com/p/StSQDFuvTAa.

Comment: Ah! Perfect! Thanks, @mkopriva

Answer (score 0):

I think  you  are looking for json:"-".

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal

As a special case, if the field tag is "-", the field is always omitted. Note that a field with name "-" can still be generated using the tag "-,".